# Установка хедера для скачивания файла

Tags: php, http, html

Дело вот в чем. Есть код

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file_name.zip"');
```

Этот заголовок не поддерживает полного адреса местонахождения файла. Можно ли как-то это исправить, чтоб, допустим, такой адрес можно было вставить

```
http://hostname.net/folder/file_name.zip
```

Comment: `filename="file_name.zip"` просто указывает, как по умолчанию обозвать закачиваемый файл. А чтобы начать закачку, содержимое файла надо как-то передать пользователю.

Comment: спасибо. не знал)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эм ? Вы хотите что бы пользователь скачал файл с другого ресурса ?

Если так то сделайте:

```
header('Location: http://hostname.net/folder/file_name.zip');
```

**UPD**

> > мммм нет.) я хочу чтоб с моего (того же что и страница), но скрипт лежит в одной папке а файл в другой. адрес формируется динамически.

тогда:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file_name.zip"');

readfile('/local/path/to/file');
```

Comment: мммм нет.) я хочу чтоб с моего (того же что и страница), но скрипт лежит в одной папке а файл в другой. адрес формируется динамически.

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо!!! работает!

Answer (score 1):

После всех заголовков:

```
echo file_get_contents("folder/file_name.zip");
```

Answer (score 0):

Хм,

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');       // изображение в формате JPG
header('Content-Type: application/zip'); // ZIP-файл
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); // PDF-файл
```

Далее, как сказал "Ёхарный Бабай", тока не echo, а лучше `print_r(file_get_contents("folder/file_name.zip"));` echo-й может не до конца передаться файлик )

Comment: Для универсальности)))

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

Comment: чет не получается. при переходе на скрипт выдает на закачку файл скрипта